# How to get user input and add to an array each time user give input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a todo list app which can store user inputs in local storage using javascript. I want to add user inputs into an array each time user types something. So, I did this but it only add one item per time and when I add another item, array only takes that one and removes the previous input. Each time the length is equal to one.

```js
let today = new Date;

const options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric'
}

document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = today.toLocaleString("en-US", options);

// create variables

let input = document.getElementById('input');
let addButton = document.getElementById('add');
let listItems = document.getElementById('listItems');

addButton.addEventListener('click', checktodo);

//add items to ul
function addtodo(todo) {

  let item = `
<li>
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 offset-md-2">
        <p class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">${todo}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Delete</button>
    </div>

</div>
</li>

`
  let position = "beforeend";

  listItems.insertAdjacentHTML(position, item);


}

//array part

function addToStorage(addThis) {

  let listObject = [];
  listObject.push(addThis);
  console.log(listObject);
}


//check the user input

function checktodo() {
  let newvalue = input.value;
  if (newvalue) {
    addtodo(newvalue);
    addToStorage(newvalue);
  } else {
    alert("add todo")
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <h3>TODO LIST</h3>
      <h3 id="time"></h3>

      <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input" placeholder="next ToDo">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning" id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container mt-4" id="container">
    <ul id="listItems">

    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>


  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function addToStorage(addThis) {

  let listObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")) || [];
  listObject.push(addThis);
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(listObject))
  console.log(listObject);
}
```

How it works:

- `localStorage.getItem("todos")` Fetches the todo lists so far
- `JSON.parse(...)` Changes the string returned from .getItem to an array
- `... || []` If there's no todo property already, make a new empty array
- `JSON.stringify(listObject)` Turns the modified array back to a string
- `localStorage.setItem("todos", ...)` saves the modified list back to localStorage

Edit: The code I posted will persist your todos through reboots and page refreshes, if you don't need that you can just move the array declaration.

```
let listObject = [];

function addToStorage(addThis) {

  listObject.push(addThis);
  console.log(listObject);
}
```

Comment: @JPabs can you accept the answer, helps with points

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your array with block scope inside the function that is supposed to add to it, but instead of doing that, it just creates a new array every time you call the function and then the array goes out of scope when the function returns.

Move this:

```
let listObject = [];
```

outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your Array listObject is local to your method addToStorage. There fore its re initiated every time.
Make it to global. Move it out side.